# Online Database for iPhone App Using Core Data

Tags: iphone, mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, core-data

My iPhone app currently uses core data.  I want to create an online database where I can sync data from my iPhone.  I also want to store user account info.

Are there any shortcuts or benefits because I am using core data?

I'm thinking I will have to have a 3 tier system for this:

iPhone using Objective Resource (iPhone on Rails and ObjectiveResource; Making communication between the iPhone and a Rails web-service pain-free.) -> Ruby on Rails -> MySQL

BTW, I plan to use twitter sdk for login/registration if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [reskit](http://restkit.org) Reskit is similar to objective resource, but has more features, including integrating with core data for caching.

Restkit also has the advantage of being backend independent, its can work with any restful interface.

Comment: Wow, restkit looks very promising! So if I go with reskit, do I still need to use ruby on rails, or can I just use obj-c from iPhone --> resetkit --> mySQL?

Comment: You would still need to use rails or another restful web service.  Restkit would would sit on the phone and do most of the heavy lifting for talking to your web service that is serving up content from the database

Comment: I spoke to anoter dev of a popular app and they said they just use iPhone -> RoR -> mySql. So would this be easier to do than using restkit etc?

Comment: Depends on your comfort level and time available.  All restkit is a library for iphone that abstracts away the manual task of doing calls to your the api you'd build out through Rails (or really any restful framework) So to be clear, your application would consist of two parts: the client - built with the iphone sdk + the reskit framework, and your server - built with mysql and RoR (or some other restful framework).  You could do all that without using reskit... but they've already done alot of work for you, so why not take advantage of it